# Android Custom list view with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i have list view with checkbox and if I select some item than every 9 item is selected too.
I am using onClickListener on checkbox.
Do you know how solve the situation? One item checked, but more selected.

If you wanna see my source code, just let me know and I will put there.

Thanks for help

Lukas P.

Comment: Code is always helpful...

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom ListView with checkboxes checking unchecked items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524733/custom-listview-with-checkboxes-checking-unchecked-items)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from views being recycled by Android. You need to store the check box state of each row in some container (eg. a list) and then explicitly set the checked state to the correct state in getView.

See this similar question:
[custom ListView with checkboxes checking unchecked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524733/custom-listview-with-checkboxes-checking-unchecked-items)